# Detect if mouse button is down when the mouse entered active area (mouse was pressed down outside this area)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am new to JavaScript so I might be missing something obvious here, but this is the problem. I am not getting the mouse down / up event if the event happened outside the active area under JavaScript control, so if the mouse enters the active area (`onmouseover` event) with the left button down, is there a way to know that the button is down?

Added info : Ideally, I would like to keep track of the mouse even outside the browser window - the way Google maps does - try clicking down the mouse button and move outside the browser - this works in chrome and with some quirks in Firefox. Is it possible to do this while remaining within the bounds of JavaScript or is it some proprietary stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: ensure that the mouse event handlers to detect a mouse-down event are attached to some element that occupies the entire viewport. For instance the HTML (document) element...

Comment: Apologies, I would like to track this even if the mouse is outside the browser... I have added some more information to the question.

Comment: Not in pure JavaScritpt that I am aware of. However it is possible to use a plugin to accomplish this, for instance a Java applet can be used to track coordinates anywhere on the screen and report that back to the browser javascript.